# Maps of graded rings inducing isomorphism between Proj.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $\Bbbk$ be a field. Let $S,T$ be graded $\Bbbk$-algebras, and let $\phi:S\to T$ be a graded ring map. We can assume finite generation if things become simpler. We have that if for sufficently large $d\gg0$, the degree $d$ part of the ring map $\phi_d:S_d\to T_d$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi$ induces $\mathrm{Proj}(T)\cong \mathrm{Proj}(S)$. My question is about the converse.

> If $\phi:S\to T$ induces an isomorphism $\mathrm{Proj}(T)\cong \mathrm{Proj}(S)$, then do we have $\phi_d:S_d\cong T_d$ for large $d$?

---

According to the example given by @KReiser, I'd like to change the statement to

> If $\phi:S\to T$ induces an isomorphism $\mathrm{Proj}(T)\cong\mathrm{Proj}(S)$, then do we have $\phi_d:S_d\cong T_d$ for sufficiently divisible $d\in\mathbb N_+$?

Comment: Potentially annoying counterexample: consider any graded ring $S$ with the standard grading and $T$ to be the subring of elements whose degrees are a multiple of $d$ for some integer $d>1$. Then $S$ and $T$ have the same proj, but the map $S_i\to T_i$ is only an isomorphism if $d|i$. If this is enough to satisfy you, I'll post it as an answer, but it could also be "cheating" and if you can figure out how to outlaw it, I'm happy with that as well.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for your example. I think a more natural expectation is that $S_d\cong T_d$ for sufficiently divisible $d$. Alternatively I would add the condition that $\mathcal O(1)$ bundles are isomorphic with respect to $\mathrm{Proj}(T)\cong\mathrm{Proj}(S)$.

Comment: @KReiser what is the map from S to T in your example? Doesn’t the map go T to S?

Comment: @JakeLevinson yes, you're right, that's a typo (or perhaps I swapped around $T$ and $S$ a bit between my head and the keyboard). The situation I'm trying to explain is the inclusion of the subring generated by elements of degree divisible by some $d>1$ into a graded ring - please let me know if you would like additional clarification.